# Connecting to oracle database using connection on another server

Tags: database, oracle, networking

we have  oracle database hosted at a third party location. we can only access that database from one server on our network. the third party only allowed access to the database from that server. our web apps are hosted on a different server and there is no way that we can open connection to the database from the web server. is there a way that we can use the allowed server to access the database from the web server which resides on the same network, kind of a centralized connection hub

Comment: Google for port-forwarding

Answer (score 0):

As a practice industry wise . From Web-Server access to the database is not allowed from security point of view . Consult your network team by sending the ping of the IP address of the database server from web server . The result will show what is happening between web server and database server